# How to request cross domain json without JSONP or control over external server

Tags: ajax, angularjs

I am building an application in Angular JS and I'm using the `$http` method to make a request to a public external API that returns data in the JSON format.

Before today I didn't really know much about the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) so I tried using a simple `$http.get` request but this was blocked obviously.

I saw that one of the ways of circumventing this was to use JSONP but the remote server isn't configured for this.

I'm very confused because I feel like I have a fairly standard use-case (need to get JSON from an API that I don't manage on my own server) and yet it seems like the only solutions I can find are about changing HTTP Headers being sent from the server receiving the response. **I don't have any control over this public API** so this isn't relevant to me.

EDIT: I've seen some articles about a solution in this situation being putting in place a proxy on a backend that I control and sending the requests through it, but I'm a bit unsure about implementing this securely, and the only [examples](http://benalman.com/projects/php-simple-proxy/) that I can find are all at least 4 years old... can anyone point me in the right direction for an easy-to-implement PHP proxy that is secure?

EDIT2: I have a standard LAMP setup.

Comment: Yes, this is your only option to get it working from the browser. In case you do not have control on the API you could develop a proxy on some backend which gives your Angular app access to the original API.

Comment: Thanks, can you give me any pointers in relation to my edited question?

Comment: One important thing you should keep in mind if you need to use the proxy approach is that many services have a request limit, either by IP or e.g. by customer id. So first check what the limits are and probably create a proxy that caches response (if possible), probably limit the request for each of your visitors yourself and what will happen if you reach the limit. And of course that it is not an open proxy.

Comment: @t.niese thanks but I think in this use case it's not pertinent because I am requesting real time data about a city bike hire scheme, so the data is subject to frequent change and I can't reasonably cache it without performing 1000s of requests each minute

Answer (score 0):

If you use Apache (from examples):

```
ProxyPass /api http://8.8.8.8:4000 connectiontimeout=5 timeout=30
```

---

If you use nginx, that sample (on your server):

```
location /api {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

            proxy_pass http://api;
            proxy_redirect off;
}
```

And somewhere before 'server {':

```
upstream api {
    server 8.8.8.8:4000; 
}
```

And your requests will be proxied on external server.

```
$http.get('/api/posts/').success(function(response) {
       alert(response);
    });
```

Comment: Okay I understand a little better how your suggested solution would work on my setup. Is it secure? It looks simpler than setting up a more complicated proxy in PHP but I'm worried this simplicity comes at a price